# Retrieving fb page info using facebook graph.. not getting picture

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can access facebook page info by going to: https://graph.facebook.com/yorganic.
But the response doesn't contain profile picture.

When i specify the fields to select like the following.. https://graph.facebook.com/yorganic?fields=id,name,picture,were_here_count i can see the picture.

Previously using the first method i was getting the picture but not getting now. Can anyone please tell me whether using the second method is safe or not? and is there any other standard way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is:

First get the Facebook User ID of the user.

Then get the picture with:

> https://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOK_ID/picture

For example: https://graph.facebook.com/100001228933230/picture

**EDIT**
You don't even need the Facebook ID of the user, you can also use

> [https://graph.facebook.com/yorganic/picture](https://graph.facebook.com/yorganic)

You can also use the Graph API Debugger tool for testing:

> http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer